# Faster way to check if a date is within a 5000+ element long list / numpy array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have the following function that is called multiple times:

```
def next_valid_date(self, date_object):

    """Returns next valid date based on valid_dates.

    If argument date_object is valid, original date_object will be returned."""
    
    while date_object not in self.valid_dates.tolist():
        date_object += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    return date_object
```

For reference, valid_dates is a numpy array that holds all recorded dates for a given stock pulled from yfinance. In the case of the example I've been working with, NVDA (nvidia stock), the valid_dates array has 5395 elements (dates).

I have another function, and its purpose is to create a series of start dates and end dates. In this example self.interval is a timedelta with a length of 365 days, and self.sub_interval is a timedelta with a length of 1 day:

```
def get_date_range_series(self):

    """Retrieves a series containing lists of start dates and corresponding end dates over a given interval."""

    interval_start = self.valid_dates[0]
    interval_end = self.next_valid_date(self.valid_dates[0] + self.interval)
    dates = [[interval_start, interval_end]]

    while interval_end < datetime.date.today():
        interval_start = self.next_valid_date(interval_start + self.sub_interval)
        interval_end = self.next_valid_date(interval_start + self.interval)
        dates.append([interval_start, interval_end])

    return pd.Series(dates)
```

My main issue is that it takes a lengthy period of time to execute (about 2 minutes), and I'm sure there's a far better way of doing this... Any thoughts?

Comment: Calling `valid_dates.tolist()` creates a new list containing all valid dates every time `next_valid_date` is called. Maybe replacing the line with something like `not np.isin(date_object, valid_dates)` could help.

Comment: Instead of doing valid_dates.tolist() every time, I instead created a new variable list = valid_dates.tolist() and then checked if date_object was in the list for the while loop. It was considerably faster at ~80 seconds. I'm currently timing your suggestion now.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem Well, I never got around to actually testing it because using numpy.isin() doesn't seem to work. For reference, I know for a fact that the first element of valid_dates is a datetime.date object '1999-01-22'. However, numpy.isin(datetime.date(1999, 1, 22), nvda.valid_dates) returns false.

Comment: A numpy array containing `datetime` objects will be slow compared to a list of the same.  If the array contains `np.datatime64` elements, working with it can be faster.

Answer (score 0):

I just created an alternate next_valid_date() method that calls .loc() on a pandas dataframe (the dataframe's index is a list of the valid dates, which is where the list of valid_dates comes from in the first place):

```
def next_valid_date_alt(self, date_object):
    while True:
        try:
            self.stock_yf_df.loc[date_object]
            break
        except KeyError:
            date_object += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    return date_object
```

Checking for the next valid date when 6/28/20 is passed in (which isn't valid, it is a weekend, and the stock market is closed) resulted in the original method taking 0.0099754 seconds to complete and the alternate method taking .0019944 seconds to complete.

What this means is that get_date_range_series() takes just over 1 second to complete when using the next_valid_date_alt() method as opposed to 70 seconds when using the next_valid_date() method. I'll definitely look into the other optimizations mentioned as well. I appreciate everyone else's responses!